# ffmpeg - how to merge two h264 videos, using one of them as alpha?

Tags: terminal, video

I need to merge two 264 videos: one of the two is a normal rgb video, and the other is a greyscale video that I would use as luma matte to make a final prores clip with alpha.

Is it possible doing it in terminal using ffmpeg?

It would be great to wrap it in a nice GUI too! (advice on making it?)

Comment: What step have you taken to accomplish this task? If it didn't work, how did it fail?

Comment: I was asking if there is a way using the ffmpeg command line that that could accomplish that task... I've got no experience using it :(